# Javamail API how can I save msg in sent

Tags: java, automation, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to sent an email from acc1 to acc2. The code seems to be working and I can find my mail on acc2. But I can't find it in the "Sent" folder on acc1. (I use yandex as an example).

I tried using imap protocol and save it after, but the code finishes without exeptions but the message still couldn't be found in sent.

**My Code:**

```
public class sendMail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String to = "TO_ACC";         // sender email
        String from = "FROM_ACC";       // receiver email

        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.yandex.ru");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("FROM_ACC","FROM_PASS");
            }
        }); // default session

        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session); // email message

            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from)); // setting header fields

            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(to));

            message.setSubject("new hjhjh"); // subject line

            // actual mail body
            message.setText("some kjkjk");

            // Send message
            Transport.send(message); System.out.println("Email Sent successfully....");

            //Copy in sent

            Store store = session.getStore("imap");

            store.connect("imap.yandex.ru",993,"FROM_ACC","FROM_PASS" );
            Folder folder = store.getFolder("Sent");
            folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);
            folder.appendMessages(new Message[] {message});
            store.close();
        } catch (MessagingException mex){ mex.printStackTrace(); }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug), and fix these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).

Comment: DEBUG SMTP: message successfully delivered to mail server
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Closing connection.
Email Sent successfully....
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "imap.yandex.ru", port 993, isSSL false

common mistakes has been fixed

Comment: so I fixed the issue
 IMAP: trying to connect to host "imap.yandex.ru", port 993, isSSL

changed to  Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
and new property
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");

Answer (score 0):

just changed **from** `Store store = session.getStore("imap");` to `Store store = session.getStore("imaps");`

also added a new property

```
 properties.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
```

Comment: Since you're using the "imaps" protocol (to connect using SSL), any mail.imap.* properties are ignored.  If you want to use STARTTLS, instead of connecting with SSL from the beginning, keep the property and switch back to using the "imap" protocol.